# Why do i end up with an empty array in my state?

Tags: reactjs

I am setting my array's state in the componentDidMount but can't understand why it shows up as empty on the mount.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentGroup: this.props.currentGroup,
        eventHold: [],
        idHold: []
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    const groupRef = firebase.database().ref('groups').child(this.state.currentGroup).child('events');
    var tempIdHold =[];
    groupRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(function(snap)  {
            tempIdHold.push(snap.key)
        })

        this.setState({
            idHold: tempIdHold
        });
        console.log(tempIdHold)
        console.log(this.state.idHold)
    })
    this.loadGroupEvents(this.state.idHold);
}
```

The first console.log shows a populated tempId array but the second console.log right underneath it shows an empty state.id array. Why?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you should also probably move `this.loadGroupEvents(this.state.idHold);` to the `setState` second callback so it is invoked when your data is ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this.setState is a async function.
So, you can use the callback in setState function

```
this.setState({
 idHold: tempIdHold
}, () => {
 console.log(tempIdHold)
 console.log(this.state.idHold)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.setState` is asynchronous which takes a callback that will invoke after the operation is finished try adding it and see the result

```
this.setState(
  { idHold: tempIdHold },
  // our updated state will be available in our callback
  () => console.log(this.state.idHold)
);
```